# Error while using mloginfo m-tools

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to analyze log file of mongodb. I am referred to use m-tools. But I'm getting following error.

I've typed in terminal

```
mlonginfo /..logfilelocation../ --queries
```

Error:

```
QUERIES [==============================          ] 74.1 % Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mloginfo", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mtools==1.1.8', 'console_scripts', 'mloginfo')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/mloginfo/mloginfo.py", line 82, in main
    tool.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/mloginfo/mloginfo.py", line 77, in run
    section.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/mloginfo/sections/query_section.py", line 51, in run
    for i, le in enumerate(logfile):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/util/logfile.py", line 208, in __iter__
    le = self.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/util/logfile.py", line 190, in next
    ret = le.set_datetime_hint(self._datetime_format, self._datetime_nextpos, self.year_rollover)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/util/logevent.py", line 246, in set_datetime_hint
    if not self.split_tokens[self._datetime_nextpos-1][0].isdigit():
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VigneshKalai [mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) is a program used to provide various ultity functions and "tools" for mongodb log analysis, starting test clusters etc etc. Basically a "swiss army knife" for playing with logs and setup configurations. It is or was developed my a member of staff for MongoDB ( not sure of current status ). I would therefore suggest a "bump" to the author or at least raise an issue on github. And if the judgmental downvote is yours in accompaniment to your comment ( which is not valid here ) then perhaps you should retract it.